# a password filed for login users using ObjectBox Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, model, nosql, objectbox

How to save password's field Using Object Box in Flutter?

I am doing a login form.but i can't find any encryption or something where i can save password in encrption like mysql does .

thank you

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding ObjectBox does not provide this. However, you can use a different package or own code to encrypt the password and then to store that string